# Android request images from web server with user criteria

Tags: android, image, webserver

What is the correct technique used to request images from a web server according to a user selected criteria?

I am referring to a shop-like application where, for example, the user selects to see "t-shirt AND size M AND black color". I assume the web server is organized with a database with picture names and categories and a separate folder to store pictures (which I do not know if is the correct approach to the situation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an **API support**. Whenever user selects or filters data you need to hit API and retrieve data. API will filter data on server side as per filters requested from user and sends you required data, you need to parse and show it to the user.

Other way can be your API will return all the data and you filter on device but its not recommended as your app can **run out of memory**. Better design your API with filter parameters.

Comment: thanks for the answer, could you please extend a bit?, I have no idea about it.... what API? where to learn about it? etc..any useful info, thanks again.

Comment: API is an endpoint for you. Normally its called web services. It will interact with database and handles back end logic for you. It's like URL you hit. You do network call from mobile client to that endpoint and you can retrieve data in JSON/XML format (e.g. REST/ SOAP).
See this is open weather API: **https://openweathermap.org/current**
You hit this url with required headers and you will receive data. Same for your case you should have/develop API for your app.

Comment: This is for what is web services: http://www.service-architecture.com/articles/web-services/web_services_explained.html

Comment: ok for what I have been reading, it looks like the API might be for example a php running in the server that will respond, for example, with JSON code of images, and then, on the android side, parse the JSON to get url of the images and display them, an I correct?